# How to detect type of toolbox item by name in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, detect, toolbox

Lets say I know an item with a name "xx" from toolbox exist, but I do not know what type is it. Is it a textbox? Is it a chart? Is it a checbox? How do I find out, I only know the name.

Comment: Missing context here. Are you building a VS add-in? How did you get to know the name of a ToolBox item?

Comment: Well I allow users to add different toolbox items themselfs, and since I cannot update source each time I want to autodetect them. I know I can store in one SQL database what kind of item it is, but I was thinking is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the controls collection of the Form to get the type of the control by control name. Then use the name property of the type. If you are creating a new control of that type use the T (type) directly.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim T As Type = Controls("TextBox1").GetType
    Dim TypeName As String = T.Name
    Debug.Print(TypeName)
End Sub
```